# EOF Alternative for calling ArangoDB query on Octave

Tags: docker, debian, command-line-interface, octave, arangodb

So I have been having this problem for quite some time. What I wanted was to run this query on Octave.

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @- --dump - --user "root:" http://localhost:8529/_db/test/_api/cursor <<EOF
{
"query" : "FOR x IN collection RETURN x
}
EOF
```

^^^^This is what I have written on to the terminal and it works fine.

But when I run the same script on Octave it turns out that there is a problem with the EOF command that I used.

```
raw=system("curl -X POST --data-binary @- --dump - --user \"root:\" http://localhost:8529/_db/test/_api/cursor <<EOF
{
\"query\" : \"FOR x IN collection RETURN x\"
}
EOF")
```

I may be wrong on the Octave syntax but is there a way to make this work or an alternative for this?

Comment: simply feed your input without the EOF as parameter. Or use "urlread" in GNU Octave

Answer (score 1):

You should probably rather use the [embedded curl support of octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/URL-Manipulation.html) .

This should avoid the overhead of having to fork a cURL, plus solve your escaping problems of here documents.